# How can i download .exe file from web and run it automatic

Tags: windows, script

I need to create some script (maybe .bat/.vbs or something else) or something else that will download and open the file on double-click. Can you say how can i do this?
Example:
I double-click on file (run.bat) and it goes to the link: http://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewer_Setup_en.exe
download and install this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use it for TeamViewer you could use [Ninite](https://ninite.com/). Here you can select what applications you want to install, and it will download them and install them without further questions asked. It also has a [silent mode](https://ninite.com/help/features/silent.html) if you want total silence.

If you are looking for something more general I would suggest you use a combination of `wget` and batch scripts. But the file you want to install *must* have a silent mode.

You will probably also run into the problem of the windows UAC kicking in at some point. You could make this more straight forward by forcing it to appear right at the beginning. by using this script:

```
@echo off

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "%params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------
```